# How to set a multi line value from drush vset

Tags: 7, drush, configuration

I was trying to add a value to the drupal antibot antibot_form_ids variable.

```
drush vget antibot_form_ids
```

returns a string separated by /r/n
Adding just a value to this string isn't just enough.
If you do a
`drush vset antibot_form_ids 'webform_*\r\nuser_login\r\n`
and so on you end up with exactly this value in the form field of the config area.

So how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just put my drush code in a text editor like this:

```
drush vset antibot_form_ids "webform_*
user_login
any_other_form
even_more_values" -y
```

Then copy & paste the whole statement to your command line and voila the values are set correctly.